# How to map a list of strings to an integer attribute in Ruby on Rails using Formtastic syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, formtastic

In my ActiveAdmin application, I have a `Country` model which has an integer attribute `schedule` with limited range of values from `0` to `4`.

In `new` and `edit` action forms, I would like to select a string from a drop-down box and map it to a corresponding integer value rather than entering the integer value itself directly.

How could I do that using the `Formtastic` gem syntax?

Comment: You probably should be using built-in rails enums or even better the simple_enum gem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See doc about SelectInput [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/SelectInput).
I think it looks like:

```
<%= f.input :schedule, :as => :select, :collection => 1..4 %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I mean I would like to see `none`, `weekly`, `bi-weekly`, and so forth in my drop-down instead of integer values, but map them to integer values.

Comment: I see. Then try 
'collection => [["none", 1], ["weekly", 2]]' ...and so on